# C#. BitArray. How shift bits to the left or to the right?

Tags: c#, bit-shift, bitarray

Trying to implement the Present cipher. I have function:

```
static byte[] getRoundKey(byte[] K)
{
    return null;
}
```

Function must working like this:

[image]

I think, if i use `var bits = new BitArray(K)`, then i can't shift it to the left or to the right. How can i do the bitshift in "true way" with byte array or with bit array?

**P.S.**

I solve my problem in that way:

```
static BitArray cyclic_shift(BitArray bits, short shift)
        {
            /*
            Сдвигает битовый массив на указанное смещение вправо (если смещение положительное) или влево (если смещение отрицательное)
            */
            BitArray result = new BitArray(bits.Length);
            for (byte i = 0; i < bits.Length; i++)
            {
                result[i] = bits[(bits.Length - (shift - i)) % bits.Length];
            }
            return result;
        }
```

If you're know better way to do this, please post answer in comments. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean like `0x01A4 << 8`?

Comment: @SimpleVar, yes that's exactly what i ment.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, is for-loop best idea to shift that type of data (bitArray or byteArray)?